# Boostrap. Como puedo alinear todas las cajas de este ejemplo en horizontal en pantallas de resolución de más de 1024 pixeles

Tags: bootstrap

¿Qué podría hacer en boostrap para que en el ejemplo siguiente resulten alineadas en horizontal todas las cajas en pantallas de resolución superior a 1024 ? No consigo que el último grupo de botones se  quede a la altura del resto de cajas debido a las etiquetas que estás tienen. 
Gracias

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <title>prueba de alineacion </title>
 


 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
 
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 
  
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.15/jquery.mask.js"></script>
 
 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="xcss/datapicker.css">

<script>



 $(document).ready(function () {
 

  
  $.datepicker.regional['es'] = {
    closeText: 'Cerrar',
    prevText: '< Mes anterior',
    nextText: 'Mes Siguiente >',
    currentText: 'Hoy',
    monthNames: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
    monthNamesShort: ['Ene','Feb','Mar','Abr', 'May','Jun','Jul','Ago','Sep', 'Oct','Nov','Dic'],
    dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado'],
    dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Lun','Mar','Mie','Juv','Vie','Sab'],
    dayNamesMin: ['Do','Lu','Ma','Mi','Ju','Vi','Sa'],
    weekHeader: 'Sm',
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    firstDay: 1,
    isRTL: false,
    showMonthAfterYear: false,
    yearSuffix: '',
    showOtherMonths: true,
    selectOtherMonths: true,
    //showOn: "button",
    //Lo comentado es porque se utiliza CSS para poder el icono
    //buttonImage: "img/calendar.gif",
    //buttonImageOnly: true,
    buttonImage: "",
    buttonImageOnly: false,
    buttonText: ""
    
   };

  $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional["es"]);

    


   // Por defecto se muestra un dia con LIMITE_POR_DEFECTO


 $("#dpFechaMinima").datepicker({
     onSelect: function(fecha) {

       console.log("Selected Minima date: " + fecha + ", Current Selected Value= " + this.value);
       $(this).change();
     }
     
   }).on("change", function() {
    var fecha = $("#dpFechaMinima").datepicker("getDate");

      console.log("Cambio en fecha minima que provoca cambio en fecha maxima a " + fecha);
  
     if( !fecha){
       limitePorDefecto();
     } else {
      fecha.setDate(fecha.getDate() + 30);
   $("#dpFechaMaxima").val(fmtFecha4(fecha));
     } 
   }).mask('99/99/9999');


   
 // Maxima fecha del limite máximo es la fecha actual

 $("#dpFechaMaxima").datepicker({
     onSelect: function(fecha) {
       console.log("Selected Maxima date: " + fecha + ", Current Selected Value= " + this.value);
       $(this).change();
     },
     maxDate: new Date()
   }).on("change", function() {
     console.log("Change event");
   }).mask('99/99/9999');

  
});
</script>

</head>
 
<body>
 

  <div id="contenedorSeleccion" class="container-fluid">
       
            <div class="row">  
     <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="control-group col-md-2">
              <label for="dpFechaMinima" class="control-label">DESDE FECHA</label>
             <div class="controls">
                 <div class="input-group">
                     <label for="dpFechaMinima" class="input-group-addon btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>

                    </label>
                    <input id="dpFechaMinima" type="text" class="date-picker form-control" placeholder="dd/mm/aaaa"   maxlength="10" size="10px"  />
                 </div>
             </div>
           </div>
           <div class="control-group col-md-2">
              <label for="dpFechaMaxima" class="control-label">HASTA FECHA</label>
             <div class="controls">
                 <div class="input-group">
                     <label for="dpFechaMaxima" class="input-group-addon btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>

                    </label>
                    <input id="dpFechaMaxima" type="text" class="date-picker form-control" placeholder="dd/mm/aaaa"   maxlength="10" size="10px"   />
                 </div>
             </div>
           </div>
     
     <div class="control-group col-md-2">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="idEvento">TIPO DE EVENTO</label>
           <select class="form-control" id="idEvento" name="idEvento">
            <option value="" selected="selected">Cualquiera</option>
       <option value=1>LogON</option>;
       <option value=2>LogOUT</option>;
           </select>
      </div>
     </div>

     <div class="control-group col-md-2">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="idUsuario">USUARIOS</label>
           <select class="form-control" id="idUsuario" name="idUsuario">
            <option value="" selected="selected">Cualquiera</option>
        <option value=1>Pepe</option>;
        <option value=2>Juan</option>;
        <option value=2>Maria</option>;
           </select>
      </div>
     </div>

     
     <div class="btn-group col-md-4">
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" title="Refrescar">
       <span class="icon glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown btn-group">
         <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
          <span class="dropdown-text">10</span> <span class="caret"></span>
         </button>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" role="menu">
          <li class="active" aria-selected="true">
           <a data-action="10" class="dropdown-item dropdown-item-button">10</a>
          </li>
          <li aria-selected="false">
           <a data-action="25" class="dropdown-item dropdown-item-button">25</a>
          </li>
          <li aria-selected="false">
           <a data-action="50" class="dropdown-item dropdown-item-button">50</a>
          </li>
          <li aria-selected="false">
           <a data-action="-1" class="dropdown-item dropdown-item-button">All</a>
          </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown btn-group">
         <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
          <span class="dropdown-text">
           <span class="icon glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span>
          </span> 
          <span class="caret"></span>
          </button>
           <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" role="menu">
            <li><label class="dropdown-item"><input name="id" type="checkbox" value="1" class="dropdown-item-checkbox" checked="checked"> ID</label></li>
            <li><label class="dropdown-item"><input name="loginUsuario" type="checkbox" value="1" class="dropdown-item-checkbox" checked="checked"> Login</label></li>
            <li><label class="dropdown-item"><input name="nombreUsuario" type="checkbox" value="1" class="dropdown-item-checkbox" checked="checked"> Nombre usuario</label></li>
            <li><label class="dropdown-item"><input name="fechaEvento" type="checkbox" value="1" class="dropdown-item-checkbox" checked="checked"> Fecha Evento</label></li><li><label class="dropdown-item"><input name="descEvento" type="checkbox" value="1" class="dropdown-item-checkbox" checked="checked"> Descripción Evento</label></li>
            <li><label class="dropdown-item"><input name="detalles" type="checkbox" value="1" class="dropdown-item-checkbox" checked="checked"> Detalles</label></li>
           </ul>
      </div>
       </div>
     
     

         </div>
       </div>
   </div>
              
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías añadir un margin-top al div que contiene esos controles:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>prueba de alineacion </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">  
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>  
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.15/jquery.mask.js"></script>   
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="xcss/datapicker.css">
<script>



 $(document).ready(function () {     
     $.datepicker.regional['es'] = {
        closeText: 'Cerrar',
        prevText: '< Mes anterior',
        nextText: 'Mes Siguiente >',
        currentText: 'Hoy',
        monthNames: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
        monthNamesShort: ['Ene','Feb','Mar','Abr', 'May','Jun','Jul','Ago','Sep', 'Oct','Nov','Dic'],
        dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado'],
        dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Lun','Mar','Mie','Juv','Vie','Sab'],
        dayNamesMin: ['Do','Lu','Ma','Mi','Ju','Vi','Sa'],
        weekHeader: 'Sm',
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        firstDay: 1,
        isRTL: false,
        showMonthAfterYear: false,
        yearSuffix: '',
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true,
        //showOn: "button",
        //Lo comentado es porque se utiliza CSS para poder el icono
        //buttonImage: "img/calendar.gif",
        //buttonImageOnly: true,
        buttonImage: "",
        buttonImageOnly: false,
        buttonText: ""
        };
    $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional["es"]);
      // Por defecto se muestra un dia con LIMITE_POR_DEFECTO

      $("#dpFechaMinima").datepicker({
        onSelect: function(fecha) {
            console.log("Selected Minima date: " + fecha + ", Current Selected Value= " + this.value);
            $(this).change();
        }

      }).on("change", function() {
        var fecha = $("#dpFechaMinima").datepicker("getDate");
         console.log("Cambio en fecha minima que provoca cambio en fecha maxima a " + fecha);

        if( !fecha){
             limitePorDefecto();
        } else {
            fecha.setDate(fecha.getDate() + 30);
            $("#dpFechaMaxima").val(fmtFecha4(fecha));
        } 
      }).mask('99/99/9999');

    // Maxima fecha del limite máximo es la fecha actual

    $("#dpFechaMaxima").datepicker({
        onSelect: function(fecha) {
          console.log("Selected Maxima date: " + fecha + ", Current Selected Value= " + this.value);
          $(this).change();
        },
        maxDate: new Date()
      }).on("change", function() {
        console.log("Change event");
      }).mask('99/99/9999');
});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="contenedorSeleccion" class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">       
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="control-group col-md-2">
                    <label for="dpFechaMinima" class="control-label">DESDE FECHA</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <label for="dpFechaMinima" class="input-group-addon btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></label>
                            <input id="dpFechaMinima" type="text" class="date-picker form-control" placeholder="dd/mm/aaaa"   maxlength="10" size="10px"  />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group col-md-2">
                    <label for="dpFechaMaxima" class="control-label">HASTA FECHA</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <label for="dpFechaMaxima" class="input-group-addon btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></label>
                            <input id="dpFechaMaxima" type="text" class="date-picker form-control" placeholder="dd/mm/aaaa"   maxlength="10" size="10px"   />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="control-group col-md-2">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="idEvento">TIPO DE EVENTO</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="idEvento" name="idEvento">
                            <option value="" selected="selected">Cualquiera</option>
                            <option value=1>LogON</option>
                            <option value=2>LogOUT</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="control-group col-md-2">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="idUsuario">USUARIOS</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="idUsuario" name="idUsuario">
                            <option value="" selected="selected">Cualquiera</option>
                            <option value=1>Pepe</option>
                            <option value=2>Juan</option>
                            <option value=2>Maria</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="btn-group col-md-4" style="margin-top:2.5rem">              
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" title="Refrescar">
                        <span class="icon glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div class="dropdown btn-group">
                        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            <span class="dropdown-text">10</span> <span class="caret"></span>
                        </button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" role="menu">
                            <li class="active" aria-selected="true">
                                <a data-action="10" class="dropdown-item dropdown-item-button">10</a>
                            </li>
                            <li aria-selected="false">
                                <a data-action="25" class="dropdown-item dropdown-item-button">25</a>
                            </li>
                            <li aria-selected="false">
                                <a data-action="50" class="dropdown-item dropdown-item-button">50</a>
                            </li>
                            <li aria-selected="false">
                                <a data-action="-1" class="dropdown-item dropdown-item-button">All</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    <div class="dropdown btn-group">
                        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            <span class="dropdown-text">
                                <span class="icon glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span>
                            </span> 
                            <span class="caret"></span>
                        </button>

                        <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" role="menu">
                            <li><label class="dropdown-item"><input name="id" type="checkbox" value="1" class="dropdown-item-checkbox" checked="checked"> ID</label></li>
                            <li><label class="dropdown-item"><input name="loginUsuario" type="checkbox" value="1" class="dropdown-item-checkbox" checked="checked"> Login</label></li>
                            <li><label class="dropdown-item"><input name="nombreUsuario" type="checkbox" value="1" class="dropdown-item-checkbox" checked="checked"> Nombre usuario</label></li>
                            <li><label class="dropdown-item"><input name="fechaEvento" type="checkbox" value="1" class="dropdown-item-checkbox" checked="checked"> Fecha Evento</label></li><li><label class="dropdown-item"><input name="descEvento" type="checkbox" value="1" class="dropdown-item-checkbox" checked="checked"> Descripción Evento</label></li>
                            <li><label class="dropdown-item"><input name="detalles" type="checkbox" value="1" class="dropdown-item-checkbox" checked="checked"> Detalles</label></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>                      
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Eso ya lo había pensado y al final lo he hecho así. Pero soy novato en boostrap y pensaba que tal vez había otra forma de hacerlo con las clases de boostrap. Gracias.